# Random cookie check htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, security, redirect, cookies

I have found a couple of scripts on the internet like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !some-cookie-name=some-cookie-value [NC]
RewriteRule .* /some-sort-of-error/ [NC,L,R=301]
```

But my question is : Is this secure? Because it is a static cookie.
It can be set by any script.

Is there a way to set a random cookie and compare that with something to make it more secure?

Comment: apache can at least check if the cookie exists, but checking whether the cookie is VALID (e.g. contains the right value) is something better left up to a script.

Comment: So the right way to set it up is to always redirect to a .. lets say php script and do some checks there before checking the cookie in htaccess

Comment: well, you can at least have apache check if the cookie exists, and save yourself a teensy bit of cpu time from running php code that would just do the same thing anyways.

Comment: so with this approach i'm not able to random generate cookie values ?

Comment: you can generate whatever values you want. but getting apache to be able to check if those are valid values is far more work than is worth it. at least have apache check if the cookie exists, and redirect elsewhere if not. If the cookie DOES exist, then you can redirect to a script that validates the value.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up !!

Comment: I can promise you that `RewriteCond` doesn't perform a constant-time string comparison and thus an attacker could slowly, byte-at-a-time, deduce the expected cookie value by examining the response time of various cookie values. http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/11/its-all-about-time.html

Comment: Also please don't rely on random scripts you've found on the internet for security.